# Nginx Modsecurity Apache Include Equivalent

Tags: security, debian, apache-http-server, nginx

I just switched from apache to nginx and so far I've been pretty happy. However, I've been having some issues with modsecurity. Back when I used apache I could use the following to add every rule I wanted from the owasp crs:

```
    <IfModule security2_module>
            Include conf/crs/modsecurity_crs_10_setup.conf
            Include conf/crs/activated_rules/*.conf
    </IfModule>
```

Now with nginx, I am no longer sure what the equivalent of this is. Including rules like this doesn't seem to work and nginx won't start. Is there a direct equivilent?